# Ethernet and wireless networking disabled Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server

Tags: networking

Please HELP urgent network problem, installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server i386

```
*-network DISABLED
     description: Ethernet Interface
     product: RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor CO., Ltd.
     physical id: 4
     buss info: pci@0000:02:04.0
     logical name: eth0
     version: 10
     serial: 00:00:db:22:19:62
     size: 10Mbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     clock: 66Mhz
     capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 
     configuration: autonegotiation=on brodcast=yes driver=r8169
     resources: irq:20 ioport:c800(size=256) memory:feaffc00-feaffcff feac0000-feadffff
*-network DISABLED
     description: Wireless interface
     physical id: 1
     buss info: usb@1:7
     logical name: wlan0
     serial: 64:70:02:2a:de:ba
     capabilities:ethernet physical wireless 
     configuration: brodcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=3.13.0-32 firmware=1.3 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Welcome to AU! While diagnostic program output is certainly helpful, it would be good if you started off to describe the symptoms of the issue you experience. Otherwise the program output may be hard to interpret. Please [edit] your question to add additional info instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try these and use manual pages to know about the commands using `man` command.

```
sudo nmcli nm enable true
```

or

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

or

```
sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

and

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

Comment: Hello Pr0sper0,

When I enter command: /etc/network/interfaces 
result is: -bash:/etc/network/interfaces: Permission denied 

For command: sudo ifup eth0;sudo ifup wlan0
result is: Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0
           Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0

For command: cat/var/log/syslog
result is: -bash: cat/var/log/syslog: Nosuch file or directory

Any other suggestion??

Comment: Please try: cat /etc/network/interfaces. Also,there is a space between cat and /var/log/syslog; please try: cat  /var/log/syslog.

Answer (score 1):

Please be more specific.

The config file to setup your nics is:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

did you try?

```
sudo ifup eth0;sudo ifup wlan0
```

You can also check the status of your nics executing

```
ip a
```

You can always check your logs to see what is happening:

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Hello Pr0sper0,

When I enter command: /etc/network/interfaces 
result is: -bash:/etc/network/interfaces: Permission denied 

For command: sudo ifup eth0;sudo ifup wlan0
result is: Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0
           Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0

For command: cat/var/log/syslog
result is: -bash: cat/var/log/syslog: Nosuch file or directory

Any other suggestion??