# Wired unmanaged after upgrading from 16.4 to 16.10 (persists after 17.04 upgrade)

Tags: 16.10, wired

I was prompted to upgrade from `16.4` to `16.10` (`edit: was just prompted to upgrade to 17.04 and same issue persists`), I did and accepted all suggested removals, updates etc and now do not have internet access via ethernet (wireless still works).

I have restarted twice, and turned modem off/on in the hopes of triggering some needed 're-configuration'.

In the system tray, when clicking on the wireless icon, next to `Wired` it just says `unmanaged`.

**Troubleshooting Below**

=============================

I tried (from https://askubuntu.com/a/2905/367134):

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/
sudo vim NetworkManager.conf
```

and changed:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

to:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

and then:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and restarted system and still have `Wired unmanaged`.

=============================

I tried (from https://askubuntu.com/a/513615/367134):

```
sudo ifconfig eno1 up
```

and restarted system and still have `Wired unmanaged`.

=============================

I tried (from https://askubuntu.com/a/547875/367134):

```
sudo ip link set eno1 up
```

and restarted system and still have `Wired unmanaged`.

=============================

Have found other posts on network issues ask for output like the following - so in case it helps:

```
sudo lshw -short | grep network
/0/100/1c/0    wlp1s0     network        Wireless 8260
/0/100/1f.6    eno1       network        Ethernet Connection I219-V
```

AND:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 3a
       serial: 00:c2:c6:a1:9f:91
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-46-generic firmware=21.302800.0 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:279 memory:df000000-df001fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 21
       serial: b8:ae:ed:7e:79:73
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:276 memory:df100000-df11ffff
```

AND:

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1e.6 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Secure Digital IO Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-V (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

=============================

Contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

=============================

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another similar post received an answer which solved problem:

https://askubuntu.com/a/905045/367134

Quoting answer:

> As [Zoltan Laczko](https://askubuntu.com/users/637434/zoltan-laczko) mentioned, from NetworkManager 1.2.4 (ubuntu
>   16.10) all non-wifi/wwan device are treated as unmanaged (see his answer in a similar question [Network Manager refusing to manage wired
>   interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838865/network-manager-refusing-to-manage-wired-interfaces)). A solution is to create an empty file:
>
> ```
> sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
> ```
>
> ... that will overshadow/overwrite the one in /usr/lib and then
>   restart the Network Manager.